# How to print each couple of args using xargs from a list

Tags: bash, xargs

I have this list

```
111
222
333
444
555
```

I want to print each line to have 2 coupled args, like this:

```
111 222
222 333
333 444
444 555
555
```

Is there a way to do this with xargs? or any single liner command (performance is important)

thanks

Comment: Nope that prints "111 222" for the first line and "333 444" for the 2nd line - not what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` seems more appropriate than `xargs`:

```sh
$ awk 'NR>1 {print prev, $0} {prev=$0} END {print prev}' file.txt
111 222
222 333
333 444
444 555
555
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `paste` with two inputs: One as the original file and one with the first line stripped off (here by using `tail -n +2`):

Using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```sh
paste file.txt <(tail -n +2 file.txt)
```

Using a [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) (as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71206138/how-to-print-each-couple-of-args-using-xargs-from-a-list/71206574#comment125868468_71206574) by @pjh):

```sh
tail -n +2 file.txt | paste file.txt -
```

Both output

```
111 222
222 333
333 444
444 555
555
```

Comment: Very nice solution.  Upvoted.  Note that you can avoid the process substitution (`<(...)`) (which has portability issues) by using a pipeline: `tail -n +2 file.txt | paste file.txt -`.

Answer (score 0):

With `xargs` and an inline shell script:

```sh
xargs -a list.txt sh -c 'while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do printf %s\ %s\\n "$1" "$2"; shift; done' _
```